# Linker issue while cross compiling for cortex-a8 device

Tags: linux, linker, arm, cross-compiling

I am using [VAR-SOM-AM33](http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=VAR-SOM-AM33) board and want to run sample code like hello world run on device and it gives -sh:./test:not found error

Toolchain used for compile code is gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux.

Code is as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
    printf("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

for crosscompile file

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc test.c -march=armv7-a -marm -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a8 -o test
```

output binary is shows as follows

```
test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=2ce1c5b3d97dac2093fe2cd2d340cdaa9989923f, not stripped
```

After copy that file into hardware and run it shows following error

```
root@am335x-evm:~# ./test 
-sh: ./test: not found
```

File permission also change by

```
root@am335x-evm:~# chmod +x test
```

but result shows same not found error.

Demo file which is running on hardware,its architecture as follows

```
root@am335x-evm:~# readelf -A /usr/bin/hello
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
Tag_CPU_arch: v7
Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
Tag_VFP_arch: VFPv3
Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
Tag_ABI_align8_needed: Yes
Tag_ABI_align8_preserved: Yes, except leaf SP
Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
```

and file which is cross compiled,its architecture as follows

```
root@am335x-evm:~# readelf -A test 
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
Tag_CPU_arch: v7
Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
Tag_VFP_arch: VFPv3
Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
Tag_ABI_align8_needed: Yes
Tag_ABI_align8_preserved: Yes, except leaf SP
Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
Tag_unknown_44: 1 (0x1)
```

Also hardware cpuinfo is as follows

```
root@am335x-evm:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 718.02
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x3
CPU part    : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 2

Hardware    : Variscite VAR-SOM-AM33
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```

I have tried running ldd command on target device.

```
root@am335x-evm:~# ldd
-sh: ldd: not found
```

So I suspect that the issue is related to the linker. 
If I simply compile the file, without linking it.

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -mtune=cortex-a8 -march=armv7  -O -c test.c -o test
```

Now if I run this file I get this error.

```
root@am335x-evm:~# chmod +x test 
root@am335x-evm:~# ./test 
./test: line 1: syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

please suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: One more thing to check would be to make sure a statically-linked build runs OK - if so, that defnitely narrows it down to a dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for solution, I found error with linker.

existing file has linker **ld-linux.so.3** and crosscompiled file has linker **ld-linux-armhf.so.3**

```
root@am335x-evm:/usr/bin# readelf -l hello

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x82fc
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  EXIDX          0x00044c 0x0000844c 0x0000844c 0x00008 0x00008 R   0x4
  PHDR           0x000034 0x00008034 0x00008034 0x00100 0x00100 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x000134 0x00008134 0x00008134 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.3]
```

crosscompiled file program header

```
root@am335x-evm:~# readelf -l test 

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x82f9
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  EXIDX          0x000450 0x00008450 0x00008450 0x00008 0x00008 R   0x4
  PHDR           0x000034 0x00008034 0x00008034 0x00100 0x00100 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x000134 0x00008134 0x00008134 0x00019 0x00019 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3]
```

after chang that linker program runs on target device.

```
root@am335x-evm:~# cd /lib/
root@am335x-evm:/lib# ls -l ld-linux.so.3      
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           12 Aug  7  2012 ld-linux.so.3 -> ld-2.12.2.so
root@am335x-evm:/lib# ln -s /li ld-2.12.2.so ld-linux-armhf.so.3
/lib/     /linuxrc
root@am335x-evm:/lib# ln -s /lib/ld-2.12.2.so  ld-linux-armhf.so.3
root@am335x-evm:/lib# ldconfig 
root@am335x-evm:/lib# cd
root@am335x-evm:~# ./test 
hello worldroot@am335x-evm:~#
```